# PDO exception only for PostgreSQL connections in Laravel but artisan commands work

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, laravel-artisan

I am new to laravel. I just migrated over to postgresql from mysql and have managed to artisan migrate all my tables and seed them via tinker. However, all of my attempts to use the boilerplate laravel auth that was working on mysql and my SQL queries are returning .

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
could not find driver in Connector.php line 55
at PDO->__construct('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;port=5432','postgres', 'password', array('0', '2', '0', false)) in Connector.php line 55
```

I have spent hours looking for solutions to this issue, I have uncommented extension=php_pgsql.dll & extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll in both production and development php.ini files, I have added LoadFile "c:/mamp/bin/php/php5.6.13/libpq.dll" to hhtp.con in Apache folder, I have composer dump autoload. the queries from laravel are not showing up in the postgres error log, which the migrate commands do. And I cannot remember how I checked but it appeared the PDO module was installed

my database.php

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'), 
 'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
    ],
```

my env

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=password
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
 QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

 REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
 REDIS_PASSWORD=null
 REDIS_PORT=6379

 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
  MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
 MAIL_PORT=2525
 MAIL_USERNAME=null
 MAIL_PASSWORD=null
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Please god give me an answer

```
C:\MAMP\htdocs\storybox1.0\public>php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());"
Array
(
[0] => Core
[1] => bcmath
[2] => calendar
[3] => com_dotnet
[4] => ctype
[5] => date
[6] => ereg
[7] => filter
[8] => hash
[9] => iconv
[10] => json
[11] => mcrypt
[12] => SPL
[13] => odbc
[14] => pcre
[15] => Reflection
[16] => session
[17] => sockets
[18] => standard
[19] => mysqlnd
[20] => tidy
[21] => tokenizer
[22] => zip
[23] => zlib
[24] => libxml
[25] => dom
[26] => PDO
[27] => pdo_mysql
[28] => openssl
[29] => SimpleXML
[30] => soap
[31] => wddx
[32] => xml
[33] => xmlreader
[34] => xmlwriter
[35] => curl
[36] => mbstring
[37] => Phar
[38] => pdo_pgsql
[39] => pgsql
```

)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twm7S.png),[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkA7R.png)

Comment: Make a PHP file that only contains `<?php phpinfo();` and check if the `php_pdo_pgsql` module has actually loaded.

Comment: Please remember: command line PHP interpreter does not necessarily load the same php.ini file than Apache module or other SAPIs.

Comment: It appears to be loaded, I am using Mamp where would the apache php.ini be?

Comment: so PhpInfo() is showing the right php.ini, refer to image 1

Comment: I'm not familiar with third-party bundles but `php -i | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'` or something similar should show.

Comment: Both the command line and webserver php.ini are the same it appears

Answer (score 0):

I must be looking at a computer too long, My PHP.ini path from phpinfo() was different from the one I was looking at. Thanks Alvaro and Chris you were right the php.ini file was in mamp/config not mamp/bin/php